# pause android activity and it should be visible(unclickable) on screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have activity with pause button in it. Now what I want is when user press a pause button whole activity should be pause and also it should be visible.

I know through pause it is possible but I don't want my activity to be send to background.

So I have following things in my activity around 10 button in table layout, TextBoxs in table layout and timer.

So here is one example of what I want where the screen is pause. Is there any way to do this and still it should be visible OR unclickable.

[image]

Comment: No clue what you need. What do you mean by pausing the activity?

Comment: @harikris I have edited the post and included one link of what I want. Let me know if it is still not clear.

Comment: On think you can do is to start a transparent activity on pause, which is on Top of the existing activity. That activity would only have a TextView containing "Game Paused" text. Since another transparent activity is on top, the user won't be able to click anything on activity below.

Comment: I added the picture for you. Basically he wants to pop up a pause menu and not have the main activity disappear from the background

Comment: You can also have a custom dialog, which is not cancelable.

Comment: @ShobhitPuri your first trick works. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On thing you can do is to start a transparent activity on pause, which is on Top of the existing activity. That activity would only have a TextView containing "Game Paused" text. Since another transparent activity is on top, the user won't be able to click anything on activity below.